# Makefile for Multiple Executables

Tags: c, makefile

I'm struggling to create a makefile for two executables

I want to be able to create a makefile that builds everything and then executes exec1 and exec2

I've got the following files with the headers included

array.c: array.h const.h

exec1.c: exec1.h array.h

exec2.c: exec2.h array.h

What I currently have for my makefile is:

```
MAINS = exec1 exec2
OFILES = exec1.o exec2.o

all: $(MAINS)
$(MAINS): %: %.o array.h const.h
    gcc -o $@ $^
$(OFILES): %.o: %.c %.h array.h const.h
    gcc -c %.c
array.o: %.c const.h
    gcc -c %.c
```

But it's not working. It says there's undefined references to some of the functions defined in array.h

Comment: Try and explain "not working" in more technical terms. What happens? Do you get errors? If so, **please show us the exact errors you're getting**.

Comment: Generally "undefined references" is not a problem related to your `Makefile`, but to your code. It's not clear if this is a linker or compilation error. That's why the exact error text is important.

Comment: You want to create a separate target for each executable. `gcc -o exec1 exec2` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile format won't work like that.  Try this instead:

```
MAINS = exec1 exec2

all: $(MAINS)

# define source dependencies for each object file
exec1.o: exec1.c exec1.h array.h
exec2.o: exec2.c exec2.h array.h
array.o: array.c array.h const.h

# build for exec1 with object file dependencies
# $@ = the target to build
# $^ = the dependencies
exec1: exec1.o array.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

# build for exec2 with object file dependencies
exec2: exec2.o array.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

# generic build for object files
# $< = the source filename matching the object file
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

clean:
    rm -f exec1 exec2 exec1.o exec2.o array.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit unclear on what the error here is, but I will try to guess.
"Undefined reference" is not a Makefile issue, but rather is an issue when using GCC. We cannot see the code, but generally this means you referred to a function or variable that the compiler/linker cannot find. When linking, be sure to link all object files together:

gcc -o outputfile obj1.o obj2.o

Be sure to include function prototypes of all functions used outside of the original source file:

main.c:

```
#include"foo.h"

int main(void)
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

foo.c:

```
void foo()
{
  /*implementation*/
}
```

foo.h:

```
void foo();
```

Compile:

```
gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o foo.o -o MyProgram
```